# In Premiere Pro, is it possible to link the "Create new black video" function to a quick key?

Tags: premiere

I'm not able to find that specific function when I'm in the keyboard shortcuts menu, leading me to believe it's not possible. I'm hoping someone on here knows more than me about it! I'm on MacOS, if it's relevant. Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotkeys inside premiere are only available if they appear in the shortcut-list. However, you might be able to use an external program such as [macro recorder](https://www.macrorecorder.com/) to bind certain actions to a custom button / button-combination.

(i do not own macro-recorder btw and have not tried it for myself. I only heard that it works well with premiere.)

Comment: Thank you! Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: Autohotkey does the same thing and is free BTW.

Comment: That's true, good comment.